# Add Facebook Page To Corona SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I've created a template app in corona SDK  , and in the menu.lua file , I've added buttons to navigate between the lua files , I want one button to redirect me to my facebook page , so does anyone how to add a facebook page into Corona , and how to add a php or html script ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. Open a the page in a native.newWebView as suggested above.
2. Open the device's web browser using system.openURL("http://facebook.com/path_to_page").  This of course will leave your app for the web browser.
3. Open the page in Facebook's native app:

   if system.openURL("fb://page/7844589738") then
        -- successful opening
    else
        system.openURL("http://facebook.com/path_to_page")
    end

This will fall back the web browser if it can't open the page or if the app isn't installed.  The number is the Facebook Page ID Number.

Comment: tried all options and none worked correctly , could you send a demo.lua file to look at it ? It is always showing a black screen and none a single error is shown in the Simulator Outpot

Comment: This is a working block:
system.openURL( "https://www.facebook.com/301953956598446" )

By the way, this kind of links ( links with id ) will try to open the page from facebook app. So simulator may cause problem, buy xcode simulator or devices work fine. To open from simulator, you should get the url, which you can copy paste from your browser. 
system.openURL( "

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı Is there a way to see how to call other apps?  (Such as Twitter, Google+, Pinterest)   I haven't been able to find a listing of what other apps native app URL would be.

Comment: Just call system.openURL("http://facebook.com/path_to_page")... if you go with option 3, somehow Facebook App cannot open the page (instead it crashes!) from my testing. And just like @DoğancanArabacı said, it will open the page from facebook app automatically if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use native.webView to open the web and request to go to facebook page. but if you need to get data or publish to wall corona support facebook you can visit this link and see if this can help you because it's unclear to me what will you do if you add facebook to your app

http://www.coronalabs.com/facebook/